# Customize stylelinks.jsp doesn't have any effect on IBM Connections on prem

Tags: html, jsp, websphere, ibm-connections

I want to include custom CSS without rewrite or other changes by connections. Found out that the IBM css is loaded in `customization/common/nav/internal/stylelinks.jsp`

Example from the last line in the original file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="lotusSpritesStylesheet" href="<c:out value="${urlWebResources}" />/web/_style?include=com.ibm.lconn.core.styles.oneui3/sprites.css&etag=<lc-cache:versionStamp />"></link>
```

With my test code the end of those file look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="lotusSpritesStylesheet" href="<c:out value="${urlWebResources}" />/web/_style?include=com.ibm.lconn.core.styles.oneui3/sprites.css&etag=<lc-cache:versionStamp />"></link>
<!-- myTest -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="lotusSpritesStylesheet" href="my-test.css" />
<script>var myTest = true; </script>
```

I don't see neither the css file or the `myTest` js var in the page source of my connections homepage.

What I've done so far:

- [Enabling live debugging](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYGQH_6.0.0/admin/customize/t_customize_enable_custom_debugging.html)
- Test customizing on `customization/common/nav/templates/login.jsp`: Here everything works, also with live debugging
- Restart the whole WebSphere cluster

[Customizing the login.jsp is documentated](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYGQH_6.0.0/admin/customize/t_admin_common_customize_login_screen.html). Isn't is possible to make changes on `stylelinks.jsp` the same way? Or does IBM only include the `nav/templates` folder for overriding without `nav/internal`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add global css changes in the file cutomization/themes/hikariTheme/custom.css Or you can have a look at the IBM ComponentPack's customizer ( https://github.com/ibmcnxdev/customizer ) which makes cusomization much easier. No more restarts and the use of latest css versions.

Comment: Both ways I already tried: Customizer is buggy, `custom.css` have issues with image paths and caching. Addiny the style on my own works fine. But currently it's in `header.jsp`. I want to have it directly after the default stylesheets, so that we can e.g. override it from xcc.

Comment: embedding custom css in jsp can be frustrating as the engine does not support latest css features....